# c# Set model for array of string

Tags: c#, arrays, string, model

I've created the following model

```
public class ListLavorationCodeClient
{
    public string LavorationsCode { get; set; }
}
```

In my code I've written:

```
var listLavorationsCode = new ListLavorationCodeClient()
{
    LavorationsCode =  codiceLavorazioneXx 
};
```

and the result is the following:

```
{
    "LavorationsCode": "30410040136042700157"
}
{
    "LavorationsCode": "30440040136042700157"
}
```

Instead I want a result like this:

```
{
   "LavorationCode": { "30410040136042700157", "30440040136042700157" }
}
```

How can I fix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the variable itself:

```cs
public string[] LavorationsCode { get; set; }
```

Comment: The problem is that I have to add the string to an existing file json using the same model.

Comment: if you cannot change the model then you will have to create a little function that converts the input to your desired output